# Problems installing Flagmatic

Tags: macos, terminal, installation, sage

I'm trying to install [Flagmatic](http://flagmatic.org/) on Mac OS X Yosemite, a software package used to solve problems in extremal graph theory using the "flag algebras" developed by Razborov. I'd like to use Flagmatic to help with a research problem I'm working on, but I'm finding it very difficult to install. I'm a mathematician and while I've had some experience using `Sage` and `Python` through the Terminal I don't really know how to fix the sort of problems that I'm running into here. [Here](http://flagmatic.org/static/pdf/UsersGuide.pdf)'s the most up-to-date user guide so you can follow what I'm trying to do. I can broadly break down the problem as follows:

First, there is a link in the user guide to download the semidefinite programming package `CSDP` which Flagmatic needs in order to do some calculations. You then need to move `CSDP` to somewhere Flagmatic can find it, so I typed

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/csdp/usr/local/bin/
```

into Terminal, which seemed to work. Then the user guide says by typing

```
csdp
```

into Terminal it should launch `CSDP`. This doesn't work - I get a `permission denied` message even though I typed `sudo`. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to remedy it?

Secondly, when I run Sage (maths software) in the Terminal, I then want to be able to change directory to the pkg folder where there is a script called `setup.py`. When I run sage and type

```
python setup.py install
```

or

`-python setup.py install`

while in the pkg directory, I get an `invalid syntax` message with a pointer to the particular phrase `setup.py`. This is what the user guide tells you to do. If I instead try to install outside of Sage I get an error message `The environment variable SAGE_ROOT must be defined`. Can anyone provide some explanation and help with how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is somewhat dated information that they provide, since for [well over a year csdp is an experimental Sage package](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14505).  You should be able to just do

```
sage -i csdp
```

to install it (if you have compiler tools, which you probably do in this case).  I guess the old instructions would still work but are a little brittle w.r.t. Sage.

Anyway, to the actual problem.  You need to do the exact command given in the instructions:

```
sage -python setup.py install
```

However, this assumes (!) that you have a `sage` command in your `PATH`.  Which you may not!

In this case, I recommend you use whatever command you use to run Sage, but instead of just typing `/commmand/for/sage` do `/command/for/sage -python setup.py install` in that directory.  It will have all the right environment variables set up so that it installs in the right place, I am guessing.

Now, I'm not sure why flagmatic isn't just having themselves become an upstream package on the Sage servers, but that is a question that is harder to answer.

Comment: Also, this will probably fix the errors you see, but it looks from the code like the package may still not install - see e.g. https://github.com/jsliacan/flagmatic-dev and the fact that the needed commit for Sage > 6.0 https://github.com/emil79/flagmatic/commit/9080b4e0d530727a61a47b3674efc20187843389 is from well after the last 'official' release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I've never launched sage from a command and instead just use the sage toolbar to start a terminal session. I'll create a command and then try your recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

I might udpate the documentation in the near future. For now, however, you might want to visit this: https://github.com/jsliacan/flagmatic-2.0.git. I keep Emil's copy of Flagmatic 2.0 with updated install info. If you follow the README file, you should be fine.

I just built sage on Yosemite from source (worked fine) and then installed Flagmatic 2.0 (or Flagmatic-dev) without difficulties. It should work for you too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: See http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/17391 - it would be really good to have ONE Flagmatic site/version, as well as using the standard Sage optional package formalism, to make it as easy as possible for others to use it.